# Alexa skill - retrieve customer mail address node.js

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I can't understand the way to use the the method to retrieve the customer mail in Alexa

The doc says to make a request with a token.

https://developer.amazon.com/fr/docs/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html

Then I have done that :

```js
function AlexaRequest(accessToken){
  Host: api.amazonalexa.com
  Accept: application/json
  Authorization: Bearer +accessToken+
  GET https://api.amazonalexa.com/v2/accounts/~current/settings/Profile.email
}
```

2 questions 
1 - Why do I get a "Parsing Error" : Unexpected Token https ?
2 - How do I get the response from Alexa ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you using Node.js sdk v2?

Comment: Yes through a node.js server on Glitch.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use **UpsServiceClient** methods to get user's Personal Information.

Follow the steps below or watch detailed tutorial [**HERE**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Xfn5kNWbnU)

**Step 1:** Write this code in your intent handler

```js
const GreetMeIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'GreetMeIntent';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const { requestEnvelope, serviceClientFactory, responseBuilder } = handlerInput;
    const token = requestEnvelope.context.System.user.permissions &&
      requestEnvelope.context.System.user.permissions.consentToken;
      
    if (!token) {
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak('Please Provide Permissions!')
        .withAskForPermissionsConsentCard(['alexa::profile:email:read'])
        .getResponse();
    }

    let {deviceId} = requestEnvelope.context.System.device;
    const upsServiceClient = serviceClientFactory.getUpsServiceClient();
    const email = await upsServiceClient.getProfileEmail();
    
    let speechText = `Hello! Your email is ${email}`;

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(speechText)
    .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechText)
    .getResponse();
    
  },
}
```

**Step 2:**  Add **withApiClient** in your exports

```js
exports.handler = skillBuilder
  .addRequestHandlers(
    GreetMeIntentHandler
  )
  .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
  .withApiClient(new Alexa.DefaultApiClient())
  .lambda();
```

Comment: Hello Ussama,

 thanks for your answer.

I tried, it work when the email permission is not granted (I get the right message). However I get an <Audio only response> when i test with a email permission granted (in a test environment) Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: What does the logs say? did you try to log the email?